# Hadith or verse related to long nails?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, reference-request

I love to have long nails, so i do not cut them.kindly guide in the light of  Islam, what should i do? my class mate and different  people ask me that why you have long  nails but its my opinion to have them.please guide me that Islam does not restrict about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Islam does restrict it as the only hadith about nails is that they should be cut and kept short.

> Five are the acts of fitra: circumcision, removing the pubes, clipping
>   the moustache, cutting the nails, plucking the hair under the armpits.
>
> https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/65
>
> "A time limit was set for us, by the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), regarding
>   trimming the mustache, clipping the nails and plucking the pubes; we
>   were not to leave that for more than forty days," on one occasion he
>   said: "Forty nights."
>
> https://sunnah.com/urn/1000140